# Getting named functions from an sequence of parameter values applied to a parametric function

Tags: differential-equations, list-manipulation, indexed-variable

The general question is how can I loop on names and indices?

An example:

I have

```
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[t] == a y[t], y[0] == b}, y, {t, 0, 10}, {a,b}]
```

and I want

```
y11 = pfun[1, 1]
y12 = pfun[1, 2]
...
```

How can I generate a list of $yXY$ with $X=a$ and $Y=b$?

Comment: `y = Table[pfun[a, b], {a, 1, 3}, {b, 1, 5}]`?

Comment: `y = pfun @@@ Tuples[{Range[3], Range[5]}]`?

Answer (score 4):

It is a common mistake of beginners to think they need names to refer to the results of `ParametricNDSolveValue`. I don't say naming is never needed, but it is very seldom needed.

Suppose you wanted to see a plot of the curves that you suggest labeling y11, y12, ..., y14. This can be done without labeling:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[pfun[1, b][t], {b, 4}]], {t, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: plot]

This approach also has the advantage of allowing you to use parameter values which  are not integer index values, which I think will be something you will want to do.

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[pfun[.12, b][t], {b, 4}]], {t, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: plot]